# Reading a json file asynchronously, the object property results are always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a Json file, it contains connectionstring. I want to asynchronously read the file and deserialize it to a ConnectionString object and I always get a null result. I'm using .NET Core 6 and System.Text.Json.

Here is contents of my Json file:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "ConnStr": "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyData;Integrated Security=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Persist Security Info=False;Async=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=sa;Password=MySecret;",
        "ProviderName": "SQLServer"
    }
}
```

Here are the contents of my classes:

```
internal class DBConnectionString
{
    [JsonPropertyName("ConnStr")]
    public string ConnStr { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("ProviderName")]
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }

    public DBConnectionString()
    {

    }
}



public class DBConnStr {
    private static string AppSettingFilePath => "appsettings.json";

    public static async Task<string> GetConnectionStringAsync()
    {
        string connStr = "";

        if (File.Exists((DBConnStr.AppSettingFilePath)))
        {
            using (FileStream sr = new FileStream(AppSettingFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                //string json = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

                System.Text.Json.JsonDocumentOptions docOpt = new System.Text.Json.JsonDocumentOptions() { AllowTrailingCommas = true };

                using (var document = await System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.ParseAsync(sr, docOpt))
                {
                    System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions opt = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions() { AllowTrailingCommas = true, PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

                    System.Text.Json.JsonElement root = document.RootElement;
                    System.Text.Json.JsonElement element = root.GetProperty("ConnectionStrings");

                    sr.Position = 0;

                    var dbConStr = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<DBConnectionString>(sr, opt);

                    if (dbConStr != null)
                    {
                        connStr = dbConStr.ConnStr;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return connStr;
    }
}
```

The following is the syntax that I use to call the GetConnectionStringAsync method:

```
string ConnectionString = DBConnStr.GetConnectionStringAsync().Result;
```

When the application is running in debug mode, I checked, on line

> var dbConStr = await
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync(sr,
> opt);

The DBConnectionString object property is always empty.

I also tried the reference on the Microsoft website, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0 but it doesn't work succeed.

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace DeserializeFromFileAsync
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            string fileName = "WeatherForecast.json";
            using FileStream openStream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
            WeatherForecast? weatherForecast = 
                await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<WeatherForecast>(openStream);

            Console.WriteLine($"Date: {weatherForecast?.Date}");
            Console.WriteLine($"TemperatureCelsius: {weatherForecast?.TemperatureCelsius}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Summary: {weatherForecast?.Summary}");
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have a solution for my problem or a better solution? I appreciate all your help. Thanks

Sorry about my English if it's not good, because I'm not fluent in English and use google translate to translate it

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, if you want to read information from `appSettings.json`, you should explore more into [reading configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#appsettingsjson). There are helper classes provided by .Net for the same.

Coming back to your code, if you want to use your own code for Json Deserialization, then you need to make the following change to it.

```
var dbConStr = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DBConnectionString>(element.GetRawText(), opt);
```

where, `element` according to code shared in the question is defined as

```
System.Text.Json.JsonElement element = root.GetProperty("ConnectionStrings");
```

This ensures the Raw Json associated with the `JsonElement` *ConnectStrings* is de-serialized.

However, I recommend you to read more into Reading configurations using the `IConfiguration` and related .Net helpers.

Comment: I understand, and I should have used the configuration feature. But I want to separate certain configurations. So it can be read more easily. Thanks for your ideas and suggestions, Anu Visman